# No component content in AngularJS unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, components

my setup is AngularJS 1.5+, jasmine, karma and the issue is with testing a component together with it's template. The issue is that after compiling the component's template, it does not have the content it should.

Consider the following test snippet:

```
const ELEMENT_HTML = '<some-component></some-component>';
const scope = $rootScope.$new();
const markup = angular.element(ELEMENT_HTML);
const component = $compile(markup)(scope);
$scope.$digest();
console.log(component);
```

The template of `some-component` can have any content. The `console.log` outputs only the `ELEMENT_HTML` I specified in the snippet, with no content of the component itself. This happens when in `ELEMENT_HTML` you put any other regular HTML elements, but here I would expect to see the full content of the component I used.

It could be an issue with using incorrect modules, but testing with `$componentController` works fine. it's just compiling it and testing it together with the template that is a problem.

I will gladly provide more data, I just need to know what may be useful.

Best regards,

Tomasz.

Answer (score 0):

New day, new opportunities and ideas. It turns out that there was some module dependency that was not fulfilled. I wonder why it worked with `$componentController` and why there was no feedback in the console that something was amiss.

Anyway, case closed.